# Creating database with tables using pytest

Tags: flask, pytest

I have database configuration file database.py:

```
import os
from flask import current_app
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase
engine = create_engine(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')) #echo=True
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

def init_db():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Which i want to call from pytest file test_database.py:

```
import pytest
from api.database import  init_db
from conftest import db_session, db_engine

def test_create_database(db_session):
    init_db()
```

Thant uses fixtures from conftest.py:

```
import pytest
from api import create_app
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase
from config import TestingConfig, DevelopmentConfig
from api.database import Base

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)
    yield app

@pytest.fixture
def db_engine(app):
    engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    return engine

@pytest.fixture
def db_session(db_engine):
    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)
    Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    with Session() as session:
        yield session
```

However when i run test, it creates respectively database file test.db but it doesn't have tables inside.
Please advice what am i doing wrong and how to fix that.